# Como puedo comentar mi código en React con Eslint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, eslint

he tomado un proyecto en curso y no puedo comentar mi código (**//**)

```
const Comunidad = () => {

const [lista, setLista] = useState([]);

  //Obtengo una lista de edificios
  const listar = async () => {
      const resp = await fetch('listar');
      const body = await resp.json();
      setEdificios(body);
  }


return (

<>
...
</>
)
}
```

El error que me muestra es

```
Expected space or tab after '//' in comment  spaced-comment
```

Intenté agregarle "rules" al archivo **.eslintrc** que se encuentra en la ruta raíz, pero no ocurre absolutamente nada. Acaso es otro el archivo que debo modificar? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Y si pruebas agregando un espacio entre las barras inversas y el texto asi `// Ejemplo` o pudes agregar la regla de slint `"spaced-comment": ["error", "never"}]`

Comment: No te puedo creer, me funcionó, un espacio era la solución... Escribelo como respuesta para marcarte como respuesta correcta, muchas gracias!. Pd: le agrego esa regla al archivo eslintrc pero no pasa nada, es como que no estuviera conectado el archivo

Comment: Que bueno saber que se soluciono, es solo cuestion de prestar atención a los mensajes que te arrojan para determinar cual es la solución. No es necesario agregarlo como una respuesta, con solo saber que te funciono me conformo. De igual manera debes revisar porque no te esta tomando en cuenta las configuraciones del archivo eslint. Saludos!